# How to remove strings that start with alphabet using gsub in R?

Tags: r, string, design-patterns, matching, gsub

I have collected tweets and I would like to extract the emoji unicode from each tweet. The emoji unicode is in `<U+00001F44D>` format and I have used the `gsub` function on R to remove all texts before and after the emoji using the function

```
tweets$text <- gsub(".*(<.*>).*", "\\1", tweets$text)
```

However, because there may be several emojis per tweet, i have decided to split each column after the character ">".

In some columns, there are strings that are just alphabet characters and does not start with "<".

My question is: How do I remove the string if it does not start with a "<"?

example:

```
data$text <- c("<U+000>", "character", "abc <U+000>")

data$text <- gsub(".*(<.*>).*", "\\1", data$text)
```

the data will still include the "character" string, but I'm trying to remove all characters except emoji unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` instead of `gsub`

```
grep("^\\<", v1, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "<U+000>"
```

---

If we need to extract the emoji's and remove the rest of characters, we can use `str_extract` from `stringr`.  Specify the regex to match i.e. `<` is a metacharacter, so  we  can escape it (`\\<`) followed by one or more  characters that are not a `>` (inside the square brackets will evaluate the literal character - `^` - implies not that character) followed by the `>` (again escape `\\`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, "\\<[^>]+\\>")
#[1] "<U+000>" NA        "<U+000>"
```

If we need to create multiple columns if there are multiple elements

```
lst1  <- str_extract_all(dat$v2, "\\<[^>]+\\>")
n <- lengths(lst1) 
lapply(lst1, `length<-`,max(n)) 
dat[paste0("Col", seq_len(max(n)))] <- do.call(rbind,
       lapply(lst1, `length<-`,max(n)))

dat
#                          v2    Col1    Col2
#1                    <U+000> <U+000>    <NA>
#2                  character    <NA>    <NA>
#3                abc <U+000> <U+000>    <NA>
#4 <U+000> characters <U+000> <U+000> <U+000>
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
regmatches(v1, regexpr("\\<[^>]+\\>", v1, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "<U+000>" "<U+000>"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("<U+000>", "character", "abc <U+000>")
v2 <- c(v1, "<U+000> characters <U+000>")
dat <- data.frame(v2 = v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I think your str_extract function is great, but it does not extract every single emoji from a single text. For example, if a text is "<U+000> characters <U+000>", I would like the output to be "<U+000> <U+000>". Could you help me with this? Thank you for your help so far!!

Comment: @sharkatt  If you have multiple emoji's use `str_extract_all` and `gregexpr` instead of `str_exract` and `regexpr`

Comment: @sharkatt `str_extract_all( "<U+000> characters <U+000>",  "\\<[^>]+\\>")
[[1]]
[1] "<U+000>" "<U+000>"`

Comment: I used str_extract_all, but the output is a list. How do I turn it into a data frame, with the emojis occurring in the same tweet in the same row but different column? Sorry if this is a lot of questions.

Comment: @sharkatt  If you need it as a single string, then `sapply(str_extract_all( "<U+000> characters <U+000>", "\\<[^>]+\\>"), paste, collapse = " " )`

Comment: @sharkatt  Or do you need as separate columns for  each element extracted?

Comment: Could you show me how to do separate columns for each element extracted? I'm going to accept your answer now lol, thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: @sharkatt  I updated the answer.  Can you please check it